# Extending default layout in Magento templates

Tags: magento, magento-layout-xml

I am trying to add a page that extends my default layout. I put the content in a .phtml file, and then setup the layout like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customlanding_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <block name="content" as="content" type="core/text_list" template="quantumco/customlanding/landing_page.phtml" />
    </customlanding_index_index>
</layout>
```

Unfortunately, all this gives me is my layout without the content. I assume I am inserting the content block incorrectly, but I cant figure out how to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the content block and add your own block as a child:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customlanding_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="landing_page" template="quantumco/customlanding/landing_page.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customlanding_index_index>
</layout>
```

If your block is of a specific type (which i dont think it is based on your code example provided, then replace `core/template` with your custom block type.